Gamma Correlation using GKgamma function produces NAN
I want to calculate gamma correlation between the following two variables:
set.seed(10)
memory<-rep(1, time=100)
confidence<-sample(0:100, 100, replace=TRUE)
df<-data.frame(memory, confidence)

I tried to use both GKgamma and rcorr.cens function but in both cases I got NAN
GKgamma(df$memory, df$confidence)$gamma

rcorr.cens(df$memory, df$confidence, outx = TRUE)[2]

I know this happens because the pair of the two variables produces 0 concordant pair but is there a way to write a code to adjust the number of concordant pairs to 0.000001? If there are other solutions, I am also interested to hear.

Isn't the problem because confidence can be zero?  What if you use sample(1:100, 100, replace=TRUE) instead? Not sure what GKgamma is, but if its a gamma function, its argument(s) need to be strictly positive.
